# To get the list elements at odd places in a list made by using map function

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

This is the code that I have been trying. It reads a .txt file which contains two lists. which are respectively read by D1 and D2. In D2, I need the elements at odd position only. The code that I have tried is given below and it doesn't give me the required output. Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy


fo = open("Test_input0.txt","r")
D1=[map(int, fo.readline().split())]
D2=[map(int, fo.readline().split())]
d2 = D2[1::2]


print d2
```

The output it gives is:

`[ ]`

The .txt file content is in the following format:

```
1 2 1 3 7 6 2 9 8 1 5 4
5 10 6 11 15 15
```

Comment: Post sample file content and what output you got..

Comment: If you are using python2 then don't put `[` and `]`. Use `D2=map(int, fo.readline().split())` alone. You now have a list with one element, another list from map. So obviously `[1::2]` will not work

Comment: @BhargavRao is there any other method other than deleting the square brackets to remove this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map()` returns a list, which you then wrap in another list with `[]`. When you try

```
d2 = D2[1::2]
```

you are trying to slice from index 1 a list containing a single item. Therefore you will get an empty list returned.

You can correct it by removing the surrounding `[]`:

```
D1= map(int, fo.readline().split())
D2= map(int, fo.readline().split())
```

Or, generally considered to be more Pythonic, a list comprehension:

```
D1 = [int(x) for x in fo.readline().split()]
D2 = [int(x) for x in fo.readline().split()]
```

Now `D2[1::2]` should give you the items in `D2` at odd indexes.

You can even combine both operations in one list comprehension:

```
D2 = [int(x) for x in fo.readline().split()[1::2]]
```

which has the advantage of converting only the required values to integers.

Comment: Is there any other method other than deleting the square brackets to remove this error ?

Comment: There is the list comprehension method shown but, if you don't like that, what is wrong with removing the superfluous brackets?? Another method would be to access the first (and only) item of the list using: `d2 = D2[0][1::2]`. The best way is to use the list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
fo = open("Test_input0.txt","r")
D1 = [int(x) for x in next(fo).split()]
D2 = [int(x) for x in next(fo).split()]
D2 = D2[1::2]
```

The only problem you had is the extra `[]`:

Change:

```
D1=[map(int, fo.readline().split())]
```

into:

```
D1 = map(int, fo.readline().split())
```

And it should work too.

Comment: Is there any other method other than deleting the square brackets to remove this error ?